# System keeps freezes when spotify is open on 22.10

Tags: kernel, freeze, 22.10, spotify

When I open spotify after a few minutes using it my entire system freezes. How can I fix this problem?

```
amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: [mmhub0] retry page fault (src_id:0 ring:0 vmid:1 pasid:32776, for process spotify pid 13673 thread spotify:cs0 pid 13735)
Feb 02 22:37:26 kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:   in page starting at address 0x0000800106a20000 from IH client 0x12 (VMC)
Feb 02 22:37:26 kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: VM_L2_PROTECTION_FAULT_STATUS:0x00140051
Feb 02 22:37:26 kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:          Faulty UTCL2 client ID: MP1 (0x0)
Feb 02 22:37:26 kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:          MORE_FAULTS: 0x1
Feb 02 22:37:26 kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:          WALKER_ERROR: 0x0
Feb 02 22:37:26 kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:          PERMISSION_FAULTS: 0x5
Feb 02 22:37:26 kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:          MAPPING_ERROR: 0x0
Feb 02 22:37:26 kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:          RW: 0x1
Feb 02 22:37:26 kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: [mmhub0] retry page fault (src_id:0 ring:0 vmid:1 pasid:32776, for process spotify pid 13673 thread spotify:cs0 pid 13735)
Feb 02 22:37:26 kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:   in page starting at address 0x0000800106a20000 from IH client 0x12 (VMC)
Feb 02 22:37:26 kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: VM_L2_PROTECTION_FAULT_STATUS:0x00140051
Feb 02 22:37:26 kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:          Faulty UTCL2 client ID: MP1 (0x0)
Feb 02 22:37:26 kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:          MORE_FAULTS: 0x1
Feb 02 22:37:26 kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:          WALKER_ERROR: 0x0
Feb 02 22:37:26 kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:          PERMISSION_FAULTS: 0x5
Feb 02 22:37:26 kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:          MAPPING_ERROR: 0x0
Feb 02 22:37:26 kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:          RW: 0x1
Feb 02 22:37:26 kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: [mmhub0] retry page fault (src_id:0 ring:0 vmid:1 pasid:32776, for process spotify pid 13673 thread spotify:cs0 pid 13735)
Feb 02 22:37:26 kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:   in page starting at address 0x0000800106a20000 from IH client 0x12 (VMC)
```

Comment: Report a bug to Launchpad.

Comment: Do I have to have a certain amount of karma or points to post a question there on launchpad? Never used it and I really don't know where to submit my problem

Comment: No, you don't need any karma. Run `ubuntu-bug linux` in a terminal and follow directions.

Comment: It can be also a spotify bug too.

Comment: The information that are automatically gathered, are they from a specific timestamp? Because I can only run the code after I did a hard reset ofc since my system was entirely frozen

Comment: Look into the attached dmesg. If there are errors, then it's OK.

Comment: I dont see any retry page fault messages sadly...what should I do?

Comment: You can post the logs you have here to your report.

Comment: I found this issue on ubuntu launchpad, seems to be the same: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1995956